# Use init to act on $_POST data

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to Use init to act on `$_POST` data by putting the following code in the `functions.php` of my theme, but I get HTTP 500 error on my WordPress blog. Can anyone help me out?

```
add_action( 'init', 'process_post' );

function process_post() {
  if( isset( $_POST['unique_hidden_field'] ) ) {
      // process $_POST data here
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this for the front-end or wp-admin part of wordpress ?

Comment: Why do you want this hooked to init?

Comment: this is for the front end i am trying to catch $_POST data within wordpress page but the wodrpess clear it so i am trying init hook.

Comment: Is that all you have in the `process_post` function in your actual file, or is there more code in there that could be causing the issue?

Comment: I put it another function     into process_post and i added it to a shortcode action

Comment: We need to see *all* the code that is causing the issue! What happens when you try it with *just* the code you posted - do you get the 500 error then?

Comment: the 500 error is from another cause i am getting -1 return now